Use a shared folder in the Compose
I want to create a docker container with a Dockerfile, Compose.yaml and a .env file. In the Dockerfile I create a image based on python, the Dockerfile:
FROM python:3

RUN mkdir -p /share_data/

COPY main.py .

The .env file:
VOLUME_PATH=/home/monetillo/Documents/test
CONTAINER_NAME=sort_algorithm_docker
CONFIGURATION_PATH=/share_data/configuration.json

The Compose.yaml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  sort_algorithm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    env_file:
      - .env

    volumes:
      - ${VOLUME_PATH}:/share_data  # Mount host directory to container directory

    command: python main.py ${CONFIGURATION_PATH}

When i do: docker compose build, I have this error:
no configuration file provided: not found
The file exists and it is inside the volume_path. I also try to change the CONFIGURATION_PATH to /home/monetillo/Documents/test/configuration.json
To sump up, what i want is in the command part pass a file that is inside the volume. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks in advance

What is the exact filename of the Compose file, including any capitalization?  docker compose build won't look at anything beyond the build: block, so it isn't getting up to anything involving volumes:; I wonder if that error is about not being able to find the docker-compose.yml file itself.

@DavidMaze the name is "Compose.yaml"

@DavidMaze I think that it finds the "Compose.yaml" but it doesn't find the CONFIGURATION_PATH

I think it needs to be named compose.yaml with a lowercase c, or docker-compose.yaml or .yml for compatibility with older versions of Compose.  You might check to see if diagnostic commands like docker compose config work; if not, then it's just not finding the file at all.

Oh, now it works, thanks @DavidMaze
